# Aspectj with web application in tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, aspectj

I have an existing Web application, running in tomcat 7 server.
Now, I want to integrate AspectJ on that app, to write some aspects like @before @after, etc.

Now, My question is, what I have to do, step by step to achieve this task.

***P.S.: dont want to use Spring AOP.***

Comment: Step by step will be only on some tutorial which you could find by googling..

Comment: I have tried, but unable to find any specific one, which meets by requirement. If u have any link, you can share it

Comment: The integration of AspectJ for a web application running in Tomcat 7 is the same as the integration of AspectJ in any other Java application. Your usecase is in no way different or problematic enough to warrant its own tutorial. Which means that any tutorial about adding AspectJ to a Java project is sufficient. Those can very easily be found via google.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your build system you should look into the ajc compiler and associated tools (Maven: http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/ or Ant: https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/antTasks.html)